# I am trying to set value for custom dimension in google analytics for my website

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to google analytics and i don't realize how make it works.

We have a website and we want to capture the customerId as custom variable in google analytics in order to analyze the behavior of each user with the site.

For this, i start to use google analytics (analytics.js) a few days ago and i created a custom dimension (to know who user access).

The dimension was created with session scope because those values must be sent once per session.

After that, i add the code needed as is explained here:

ga('create', 'UA-#######-1', 'domain.com');

ga('send', 'pageview', { 'dimension1': '<%Convert.ToString(Session["SelectedCustomerID"]);%>' });

I've tried this code and others configurations but google analytics doesn't take the values.

What i'm doing bad? Please suggest me a way to capture the information.

Comment: I takes some time until it proceed into reports.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response... Do you know how long it usually takes ?

Comment: It is usuall yabout a few hour up to one day... Before, you can check if your data are going to google analytics servers. Use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna and you can see in console (F12) tha your dimension1 is passed to the server.

Comment: Thank you Jakub, in console i see like this does that mean dimension1 value is not passed to the server ?

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lhUhk.png

Comment: Good, now we know, that your macro <%Convert.ToString(Session["SelectedCustomerID"]);%> do not return any value. Check your macro.